# React Invalid hook call on the useNavigate in exported Service

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have the following code exported as CommonService.tsx and called as **COMMON.redirect('/');**

```
import { useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export function Redirect(route: string) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return navigate(route);

};

const COMMON = {
    redirect: Redirect,
};

export default COMMON;
```

But after the call of the **COMMON.redirect('/');**  I am getting the following exception:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

What should be the right usage of the **useNavigate** in the Shared Service (I would like to call one method instead of import useNavigate in several components).

Comment: It is so simple you are trying to make a re-usable utility function for your case and just think like "react router dom" already created that utility function with this name useNavigate ,

Comment: any kind can only be call in React Own Functional Component, Functional Component are thos functions which return JSX or Simple HTML not any js object or etc'

Answer (score 2):

`Redirect` isn't a React component or custom React hook so you are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> ## Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.
>
> ## Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.** Instead, you can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks

Update the code such that `useNavigate` is called in a React hook. Return your custom hook that encapsulates/returns a `redirect` function.

Example:

```js
import { useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export function useRedirect() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (route: string) => navigate(route, { replace: true });
};

const COMMON = {
  useRedirect,
};

export default COMMON;
```

Import `COMMON` or the `useRedirect` hook for use in a React component.

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const redirect = COMMON.useRedirect();

  ...

  redirect("/somePath");

  ...
};
```

This doesn't really get you anything better than just importing and using the `useNavigate` hook directly though.